# How do I remove or disable min-height for my mobile page?

Tags: css

For the mobile version of my page there are white spaces in between the images that I can't seem to remove.

When I inspect the coding and toggle the min-height on and off it goes away:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px)
.edgtf-section.edgtf-parallax-section-holder:not(.edgtf-full-screen-height-touch), .touch .edgtf-parallax-section-holder.edgtf-parallax-section-holder-touch-disabled:not(.edgtf-full-screen-height-touch) {
    height: auto !important;
    min-height: 400px;
}
```

Website: [Creationflame.com](http://creationflame.com)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`min-height:initial;`

[This sets it back to what it was originally.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial)

> The initial CSS keyword applies the initial value of a property to an
>   element. It can be applied to any CSS property, including the CSS
>   shorthand all.

Comment: I'm sorry I accepted and I upvoted sadly it doesn't show because I'm new here.  I forgot I had to accept it. >.<